# Why do clip-path ellipsis have blurred edges in Chrome?

Tags: css, google-chrome, ellipse, clip-path

Try the following in Firefox and then try it in Chrome - notice the edge of the ellipse (the green section) has a soft edge in Chrome and hard edge in Firefox
Example: https://getbase.com/products/base/

Is there a way to make the edge on Chrome solid instead of softly faded?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortuanly no because css is for all browsers and chrome handles it differently.